# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'reactor.util.context.ContextView reactor.core.publisher.MonoSink.contextView()'

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor

After upgrade Spring Boot version from 2.6.6 to 2.6.7, I'm getting below error while executing web client rest calls. Any idea?

Sample code

```
public void execute(BiConsumer<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>, Throwable> responseConsumer) {
    WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec uriSpec = getUriSpec();
    Mono<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>> responseEntityMono = uriSpec
            .uri(this::buildUri)//"localhost:1234")//
            .headers(this::setHeaders)
            .body(insertBody())
            .retrieve().onRawStatus(i -> i == 599,
            response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(body -> new ExternalException(599, body)))
            .toEntity(JsonNode.class);
    CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>> completableFuture = responseEntityMono.toFuture();
    completableFuture.whenCompleteAsync(responseConsumer);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Upgrade pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The newer versions of spring boot require the more recent version of reactor lib, otherwise, it causes this error, I didn't investigate the details but updating versions fixes the issue.
Besides errors, it uses all connections pool and transactions across application. So it hangs and everything is languid.
The proper version could be found here:
[spring dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.7/reference/html/dependency-versions.html)

Answer (score 5):

The method that can't be found is in the class MonoSink (in reactor-core project): https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/main/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoSink.java

Since this was an exception you got after upgrading from spring boot version 2.6.6, I guess that the class that can't find it is HttpClientConnect (in project reactor-netty-http). It would be good to have the whole stack exception though.

@jiangjianbo is not wrong saying that you need to update reactor-core to solve this but not to version 3.4.3. It should be at least the version 3.4.17 (That said I would take latest one, which at the time of writing this is 3.4.19). As you can see in version 3.4.16 contextView() was not yet created: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/v3.4.16/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoSink.java

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade you pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you mean to downgrade reactor dependency instead of upgrade - because the included version is 3.4.10? Also doesn't seem to solve the issue for me.

Comment: Fyi, fixed for me with spring boot 2.7.1 when setting reactor-core to 3.4.19

Answer (score 0):

You've reload Maven project.

Right click on Maven -> Reload project. After that rerun your app.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading spring boot 3.1.4 version, i need to exclude reactor core and add again with downgraded version 3.4.9. Here is the pom:

com.azure.spring
spring-cloud-azure-starter
4.0.0

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.19</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: what is this? an answer to the question? a different question and its answer?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35229449)