# Error occurs java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.core.publisher.MonoSink.contextView() after updating Quarkus version

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, quarkus, project-reactor

I have updated the quarkus version of the project from 2.13.final to 2.16.4 final. Then it gives an error as follows.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.core.publisher.MonoSink.contextView()

The dependency tree of reactor.core is as follows.

```
+- com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.37.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.7:compile
```

Any idea?

As mentioned in [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'reactor.util.context.ContextView reactor.core.publisher.MonoSink.contextView()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989222/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-reactor-util-context-contextview-reactor-core-publ) I tried changing the version of reactor-core. But it didn't fix the issue.